# linq2sql - can't execute subquery in the select statement

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

here's the scenarion - I want to get the distinct list of coordinates, and for each pair of them I want to select the MIN date from the row they're placed.

I try to execute that query, but I get the **Method or operation is not implemented** exception. So, how can I fix it ?

```
        var q = (from x in Session.Query<MyTable>()
                 where x.UserID == 1
                 group x by new { x.Longitude, x.Latitude } into cords

                 select new
                 {
an exception ->      date = (from y in Session.Query<MyTable>()
                            where y.UserID == 1
                                  &&
                                  cords.Key.Latitude == y.Latitude
                                  &&
                                  cords.Key.Longitude == y.Longitude
                            orderby y.AddedDate ascending
                            select y.AddedDate
                           ), // maybe add .FirstOrDefault() ?

                     lng = cords.Key.Longitude,
                     lat = cords.Key.Latitude
                 }
                )
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Have you tried `date = cords.Min(x=>x.AddedDate),`?

Comment: then I'd have to add the `AddedDate` property into the `cords` object, in that case I'm sure I'll see the duplicates